# Delay do timer.swing

Tags: java, swing, timer

Estou fazendo um joguinho que pisca umas imagens em ordem no frame, meu objetivo é que elas pisquem em ordem, mas elas estão piscando todas juntas:

```
public class Logica {

    List<Integer> seqAlea = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> seqInsere = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random geraNumero = new Random();
    Timer timer = new Timer(1500, null);

    public void comecaJogo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            numero = geraNumero.nextInt(4) + 1;
            seqAlea.add(numero);
        }
    }

    public void piscaImagen(ImageIcon img1, ImageIcon img1b, JLabel lbl) {
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int count = 0;
            @Override               
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if(lbl.getIcon() != img1){
                    lbl.setIcon(img1);
                } else {
                    lbl.setIcon(img1b);
                }
                count++;
                if(count == 2){
                    ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(1250);
        timer.start();
    }
```

No frame tá:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JLabel lblImg1 = new JLabel();
JButton btnImg1 = new JButton("Economize Energia");
final URL resource1 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img1.jpg");
final URL resource1b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img1_b.png");
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(resource1);
ImageIcon img1b = new ImageIcon(resource1b);

JButton btnImg2 = new JButton("Preserve o Meio Ambiente");
JLabel lblImg2 = new JLabel("");
final URL resource2 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img2.jpg");
final URL resource2b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img2_b.jpg");
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon(resource2);
ImageIcon img2b = new ImageIcon(resource2b);

JButton btnImg3 = new JButton("N\u00E3o \u00E0 polui\u00E7\u00E3o!");
JLabel lblImg3 = new JLabel("");
final URL resource3 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img3.jpg");
final URL resource3b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img3_b.jpg");
ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(resource3);
ImageIcon img3b = new ImageIcon(resource3b);

JButton btnImg4 = new JButton("Recicle!");
JLabel lblImg4 = new JLabel("");
final URL resource4 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img4.jpg");
final URL resource4b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img4_b.jpg");
ImageIcon img4 = new ImageIcon(resource4);
ImageIcon img4b = new ImageIcon(resource4b);

Logica jogo = new Logica();

JButton btnComecar = new JButton("Come\u00E7ar");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main window = new Main();
    window.setVisible(true);

}

public Main() {

    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblImg1.setIcon(img1b);
    lblImg1.setBounds(78, 48, 250, 200);
    btnImg1.setBounds(153, 259, 89, 23);
    btnImg1.addActionListener(this);
    add(lblImg1);       
    add(btnImg1);

    btnImg2.setBounds(456, 259, 186, 23);
    btnImg2.addActionListener(this);
    lblImg2.setIcon(img2b);
    lblImg2.setBounds(421, 48, 250, 200);
    add(btnImg2);
    add(lblImg2);

    btnImg3.setBounds(114, 525, 186, 23);
    btnImg3.addActionListener(this);
    lblImg3.setIcon(img3b);
    lblImg3.setBounds(78, 314, 250, 200);
    add(lblImg3);
    add(btnImg3);

    btnImg4.setBounds(456, 525, 186, 23);
    btnImg4.addActionListener(this);
    lblImg4.setIcon(img4b);
    lblImg4.setBounds(421, 314, 250, 200);
    add(lblImg4);
    add(btnImg4);

    btnComecar.setBounds(68, 14, 89, 23);
    btnComecar.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnComecar);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(btnImg1)) {
        jogo.piscaImagen(img1, img1b, lblImg1, 500);
    }  else if (e.getSource().equals(btnComecar)) {
        jogo.comecaJogo();
        System.out.println(jogo.seqAlea);
        for (int i = 0; i < jogo.seqAlea.size(); i++) {
            switch (jogo.seqAlea.get(i)) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img1, img1b, lblImg1, 500);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img2, img2b, lblImg2, 1000);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img3, img3b, lblImg3, 1500);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img4, img4b, lblImg4, 2000);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Como posso fazer com que as imagens pisquem em ordem?

Answer (score 1):

Uma das maneiras para resolver o problema é atribuir um `delay` inicial diferente para cada animação, e.g:

```
public void piscaImagen(ImageIcon img1, ImageIcon img1b, JLabel lbl, int initialDelay) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1500, null);
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        // Mesmo código da pergunta
    });
    timer.setInitialDelay(initialDelay);
    timer.start();
}
```

E no switch:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jogo.seqAlea.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
    switch (jogo.seqAlea.get(i)) {
    case 1:
        jogo.piscaImagen(img1, img1b, lblImg1, 0);
        break;
    case 2:
        jogo.piscaImagen(img2, img2b, lblImg2, 500);
        break;
    case 3:
        jogo.piscaImagen(img3, img3b, lblImg3, 1000);
        break;
    case 4:
        jogo.piscaImagen(img4, img4b, lblImg4, 1500);
        break;
    }
}
```

Dessa forma cada imagem começará a piscar meio segundo depois da anterior (você pode aumentar o delay conforme sua necessidade).

Comment: Fiz alterando o delay em cada switch e desse jeito e não deu certo, vou editar com o código completo

Comment: Oi Vitor. Veja se criar Timers separados dentro do método conforme essa versão do código funciona como esperado (não se esqueça também de brincar com os intervalos. Pode ser que você queira intervalos maiores).